# How to take back the value assign to a function?

Tags: c++, int

I want to build a simple calculation program to find the sum and total.

When I try to run it the sum and total acts like they are zero (no value assign to them), but I already did assign it.
Can anybody explain to me why this happens? How to solve this problem?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int sum;
    cout << "Enter a number \n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter another number \n";
    cin >> b;
    sum = b - a;
    cout << "Sum is: " << sum << endl;

    int c= 60 * 60;
    int d;
    int total;
    cout << "enter a number \n";
    cin >> d;
    total = c * d;
    cout << "total is: " << total << endl;

    int all;
    all = sum / total;
    cout << "all is: " << all << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For some specific input, what is the actual output you get? What is the expected output? Have you tried to use a debugger to step through your program statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: On a nitpicking note: `b - a` is not a sum, it's a *difference*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's the sum of `b` and `-a`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

For whatever reason, in your code `sum = b - a`. It seems that you mean `a + b`.

But the real issue with 'all' is that it's an integer. With integers, 5/10 (for example) is 0. To fix that, change your code to:

```
float all;
all = float(sum) / total;
```